# Early triboelectricity

Tags: physics, electricity

I am looking for good sources to quote for early work on triboelectricity. I already have the standard ones, e.g. Benjamin Park (1898) "A history of electricity..", Roller & Roller (1953) DOI:10.1119/1.1933449,Maver (1918) in Encyclopedia Americana, and Hauksbee, Gilbert, Knight, Peclet papers/books. Probably I am missing some good ones.

Suggestions please, including good modern overviews.